# Cannot install node-sass

Tags: node-sass

I'm in an environment where I am required to run a local proxy, and I am unable to install node-sass. When I try the following:

```
npm install -g node-sass
```

I get an error:

> Cannot download "https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v4.5.3/win32-x64-48_binding.node": tunneling socket could not be established, cause=read ECONNRESET

I have already installed cntlm and configured it correctly. To verify I use the porxy server to access internet and it works fine.

The following environment variables are set

```
http_proxy  ->  http://localhost:3128
https_proxy ->  http://localhost:3128
```

Have also added the following to my .npmrc

```
https-proxy=http://localhost:3128
http-proxy=http://localhost:3128
proxy=http://localhost:3128
```

Also tried by adding slashes to the end but the result is the same.

Any clues and help would be appreciated since I have no idea how to resolve this.

Additional details:

```
node -v 
v6.11.4

npm -v
5.5.1
```

Answer (score 2):

The workaround I found was to download the node-sass file from https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v4.5.3/win32-x64-48_binding.node and then set the sass-path to the binaries downloaded:

```
SET_SASS_BINARY_PATH = C:\..\..\
```

and then doing

```
npm install -g node-sass
```

worked for me.